# How do I push the results obtained from Firebase query into an array?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been able to retrieve all the necessary objects, however when console.logging them they appear as separate objects and not within an array.

I then tried to place the results into an array, however since they are logged as separate objects, my array ends up having only one object.

How do I proceed further?

The code I currently have:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) { 
        const userID = user.uid

        const objectDoc = query(collection(db, "objects"), where("user", "==", userID));


        const getObjectDoc = async () => {
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(objectDoc);
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let objectArr = []
            console.log("Objects => ", doc.data());
            objectArr.push(doc.data())
            console.log(objectArr)
          });
        }

        getObjectDoc()


      } else {}
    })
```

Comment: Don’t create a new array in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) has a `docs` property that'll be an array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot). You can use `map()` a new array containing the data like this:

```
const getObjectDoc = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(objectDoc);

  const dataArr = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
    id: d.id,
    ...d.data()
  }))

  console.log(dataArr)
}
```

For the original code, you have `let objectArr = []` within the loop that'll be empty at the start of every iteration. If you move if out of the loop, that function will work too.